# Adding shapefiles to ArcGIS Pro that only contain xxxx characters

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-pro

I have a vast number of shapefiles downloaded for Forest Management Unit data and I only want to add the ones that contain the characters "epso" to my map (without having to scroll through hundreds of files to select).

For example, the files download with several file types for each unit:

```
t1409epbo.shp
t1409epla.shp
t1409epma.shp
t1409epso.shp
t1410epbo.shp
t1410epla.shp
t1410epma.shp
t1410epso.shp
etc.
```

How do I add only the epso ones?

Comment: This should be a pretty basic Python exercise -- use the `in` operator of Python (`if ('espo' not in name): continue`) within a load all files `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will be able to do this by having your Map open in ArcGIS Pro, and using Windows Explorer to search for files using `*epso.shp`.

If you see just the shapefiles that you want in your Search Results, then use Ctrl-A to select them all, and then drag and drop them all together into your Map.

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS Pro has a good search function within your catalog pane, specific to the directory you've saved as a connection. From there they can be quickly added into the map by selecting all that return from the query for epso or epso.shp

Comment: What are the precise and detailed steps that you use to do this in the Catalog pane?  I gave that a quick and unsuccessful try before resorting to using Windows Explorer to do the file filtering.

Comment: Hi Jude! Thanks for the tips folks. Going to try them out.

Comment: It may need to index the search first? I tried it again today and if you open catalog to the folder of interest it will return faster than if you try to search at the root (without opening any file trees)